Is there an Azure DevOps equivalent to GitHub Apps?
GitHub has GitHub Apps that is basicly a web service that has a webhook and is granted selected permissions to repositories. GitHub will trigger the webhook when given events occur.
Does Azure DevOps have something similar? I would like to make a service that is triggered on ADO events and have permission to do things to a ADO Repository.

Are you possibly thinking of service hooks?

Yes, looks like it.

This functionality can be achieved, but it's probably not as straightforward as in GitHub.
AzDevOps has global notifications. You can see the full gamut of catchable events under (Collection|Organization) Settings/Global Notifications. Now, the primary purpose of those is sending e-mails, but you can also create a notification record to send a HTTP(S) SOAP request to an arbitrary endpoint. The SOAP channel used to be exposed in the Web UI, but now it's only available if you create a notification through AzDevOps API (.NET or REST). Internally it's supported as always.
The endpoint, in turn, can do whatever it needs to do via the magic of personal access tokens (PATs). Create one with the kind of permissions that you need, put it into the SOAP endpoint's config, and call away. If your AzDevOps is hosted on premises, you can use service accounts and Windows auth as well. If you have the rights to host your endpoint on the same server where AzDevOps proper is (why not?), you can even configure it to run under the same app pool as AzDevOps and enjoy full rights. The amount of configuration hassle is minimal this way.
The third component is hosting the SOAP endpoint. Does GitHub take care of hosting the app? AzDevOps doesn't. You'd need to spin up the hosting infrastructure for this. If AzDevOps is hosted on premises, you can reuse whatever Web server it runs on for the endpoint, if the ops people let you.
This is the rough outline of the architecture; I can provide details if needed.

There also release gateways, those can be an HTTP call too. Didn't experiment with those.

There are also service hooks. Again, didn't play with them. They are defined per project, not per collection/organization, and I was after a global event handling scope (as global as possible). Unlike notifications, they can't be scoped to a user or group.

It all depends on what kind events you want to hook and process. For certain events (e. g. code check-in/commit, PR merge), you can fire up continuous integration and put your desired functionality into a build pipeline (definition) and have that triggered by a repo event. Build pipelines don't look like much, but they can contain arbitrarily complicated logic via the magic of e. g. Powershell script tasks.

Thanks. Not exactly what I was hoping for. I want to trigger a service whenever somethings happens to a PR (create, update, comment, reviewed etc).
I’ll look into your suggestions, but I might end up just making a custom action that can be used in a workflow that triggers on a pr create. I’ll let you know what I end up with.

Looks like ADO Service Hooks is the closest thing to a GitHub App


I would like to make a service that is triggered on ADO events and have permission to do things to an ADO Repository. I want to trigger a service whenever somethings happen to a PR (create, update, comment, reviewed etc.).

Yes, Azure DevOps has a similar concept called Webhooks. You can set up webhooks in Azure DevOps to trigger your service when certain events occur in a pull request (PR).
Here is the Available event types, which includes

Pull request created
Pull request merge attempted
Pull request approved
Pull request updated
Pull request commented on

I also want to share the information about triggering Azure Pipelines based on these events. You can refer Generic webhook based triggers for YAML pipelines for more details. This way, you can trigger the pipeline when certain events occur in a pull request. In the pipeline, you can add some tasks to do things to an ADO Repository.

Thanks. The thing about service hooks is that it’s a one way service. If I want the service to be able to, fx add a comment to a PR, then the service needs to be granted permissions to that somehow. In a GitHub app that’s part of the concept. When a user installs a GitHub app the user also grants permissions to the app so it can do things. I cannot see that you can do the same thing with Service Hooks.

Hi @SimonK, yes, they are different. However, currently  in Azure DevOps, the Service Hooks is the closest one to the GitHub Apps. You welcome to request the feature for Azure DevOps here to help the feature better. Thanks, and happy coding! :)
